# Create dataframe from assosiation rules output in R

Tags: r, dataframe, arules

Anyone can help me on how to create dataframe for association rules obtained by arules package. I tried the different forms of  "coerce signature(from = "rules", to = "data.frame");" but i didn't get anything out of it.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is you can do it by using: as(rules, "data.frame")